# How to do this SQL query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, controller

How to do this SQL query in Rails?

I have three tables I'm trying to join. I'm pretty sure I've connected them properly in the model.

I have a few joined tables, in this case, there is an "ownership" table which has the user id and the game id. It is inner-joined with the "games" table and the "users" table. The game table has game information and has a `console` column which is joined with the console table. The console table are all the consoles in the database. In this way, when I display a game, I can display the console it belongs to.

I have created a web interface to keep up with my video game collection. I have it working in PHP, but I'm converting everything to Ruby on Rails. What I'm trying to do now is, on the inventory page, I want to display the consoles that the user has games for so the user can select a console and filter the games displayed to only show the games for that console.

For instance, the main inventory page shows every game the user owns. On the right side there's a sidebar with the consoles the user has games for. If the user only wants to see the games he has for the N64, he clicks on N64 and the display is filtered to only show N64 games.

I don't want to display a console on the sidebar unless the user owns a game for that console.

Here's the SQL query that I want to work:

```
select distinct console_general.eng_name from ownership inner join games on games.id=ownership.games_id inner join console_general on console_general.console_id=games.console_general_id;
```

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> describe games;
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ean                | mediumtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| eng_title          | mediumtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jap_title          | mediumtext | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| console_general_id | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| region_id          | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| image              | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe ownership;
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id              | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| games_id             | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| own                  | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| complete             | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| box_condition        | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| game_condition       | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| manual_condition     | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| inserts_condition    | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| notes                | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spine_card_condition | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| count                | int(11)    | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe console_general
    -> ;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| console_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eng_name   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jap_name   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is my controller:

```
class InventoryController < ApplicationController
  def test

    # These work fine
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
    @ownership = Ownership.where(user_id: 1)

    # This is the variable I've been working on, not sure if I'm on the right track or not.
    # @console =  Ownership.joins(games: {console_general: :console_id})
  end
end
```

And here are my models:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
self.pluralize_table_names = false

belongs_to :games

Ownership.joins(:games)

end

class Games < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :console_general
belongs_to :region
belongs_to :image
has_many :ownership

Games.joins(:region, :console_general, :image)
end

lass ConsoleGeneral < ActiveRecord::Base
self.pluralize_table_names = false

has_many :games
has_many :accessories
end
```

I hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

Manipulating the given answer a bit I was able to get it. The Model associations were correct, but the controller instance variable didn't work at first, here's what I did

```
Ownership.joins(:games => :console_general).uniq.pluck(:eng_name)
```

This worked great. Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :games, through: :ownerships
end

class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :users, through: :ownerships
  belongs_to :console_general
end

class ConsoleGeneral < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end
```

[Railsguide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Then for

```
select distinct console_general.eng_name from ownership 
inner join games ongames.id=ownership.games_id 
inner join console_general on console_general.console_id=games.console_general_id
```

...if the point of that is to see all that consoles that have any games then you could do:

```
ConsoleGenerals.joins(:games).uniq.pluck(:eng_name)
```

pluck selects only the eng_name, uniq yields the 'select distinct', and joins(:games) will force the presence of associated games.

Or this if you want to restrict to owned games

```
ConsoleGenerals.joins(:games => :ownerships).uniq.pluck(:eng_name)
```

Comment: It looks like this is where I want to go. I'm getting another error now: uninitialized constant ConsoleGeneral::Game.but at least it's better than the other. Thoughts? Since I built this over an existing database I don't know if my table names are causing problems with rails.

Comment: Got it, manipulated your code just a bit here's what I ended up with Ownership.joins(:games => :console_general).uniq.pluck(:eng_name)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ConsoleGeneral < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :with_owned_games, -> { joins(:games).merge(Games.with_ownerships) }
end

class Games < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :with_ownerships, -> { joins(:ownership) }
  scope :with_certain_owner, -> { |owner_id| joins(:ownership).where(user_id: owner_id) }
end
```

ConsoleGeneral that have games with ownerships:

```
ConsoleGeneral.with_owned_games
```

Uniq eng_names only:

```
ConsoleGeneral.with_owned_games.select(:eng_name).uniq
```

ConsoleGeneral that have games belonging to user with id = some_user_id:

```
ConsoleGeneral.with_certain_owner(some_user_id)
```

Uniq eng_names only:

```
ConsoleGeneral.with_certain_owner(some_user_id).select(:eng_name).uniq
```

Comment: Scopes are a nice touch here.  But using select instead of pluck to replicate a query of only one column is markedly inferior.  Select constructs full activemodels while pluck generates a simple array of results.

Comment: To elc: I sure you are wrong. http://gistflow.com/posts/328-pluck-vs-select-again

Comment: To quote from the page you linked to--"Do not forget about all of the overhead of AR instantiation that isn't done when using pluck, so that on large datasets it will perform even better compared to "select" solutions"

Comment: First of all the question is "How to do this SQL query..." ( not "How to get an array").

Comment: Correct.  And the SQL query in question only returns one column--that is what pluck does.  If it was "select *" then rails' select would be equivalent.  The array vs activerecord collect is admittedly a follow-on, but it is germane and potentially significant.